# How to get special data from xml file using c#

Tags: c#, xml

**Hi all
I have a xml file:**

```
   <bookstore>
      <book category="COOKING">
        <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
        <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>30.00</price>
      </book>
      <book category="CHILDREN">
        <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
        <author>J K. Rowling</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>30</price>
      </book>
      <book category="CHILDREN">
        <title lang="en">abc</title>
        <author>bcd</author>
        <year>2006</year>
        <price>29</price>
      </book>
      <book category="WEB">
        <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
        <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
        <year>2003</year>
        <price>39.95</price>
      </book>

</bookstore>
```

How to I can get **price list** when **category = "CHILDREN"**? I using C#.

example: Output is : price of Harry Potter is 30 and price of abc is 29

Thank,

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ to XML. Following code will return collection of anonymous type instances with all data from your XML:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("Input.txt");

var books = xDoc.Root
                .Elements("book")
                .Where(b => (string)b.Attribute("category") == "CHILDREN")
                .Select(b => new
                {
                    Title = (string)b.Element("title"),
                    Author = (string)b.Element("author"),
                    Year = (int)b.Element("year"),
                    Price = (decimal)b.Element("price")
                });
```

You can call `.First()` method on `books` to get only one/first found item.